# ASP.NET Core 1.1 routing broken, but only in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I updated my open source forum app to ASP.NET Core 1.1, and after battling deployment weirdness (it broke for reasons I don't totally understand, but believe it has something to do with the changing tooling), now I find that routing is broken. When I say it's broken, I mean it continues display links with tag and HtmlHelpers, but they don't match the "clean" routing that they used to. **They work correctly locally, but not in an Azure app service.**

For example, the correct URL should be:

https://popforumsdev.azurewebsites.net/Forums/first-test-forum

But it's resolving as:

https://popforumsdev.azurewebsites.net/Forums/Forum?urlName=first-test-forum

I get the tooling changing, but this has me totally stumped. Same code, working differently locally and in Azure, and it didn't break until I updated to v1.1. (It doesn't instill a lot of confidence for what I assume will be relatively frequent framework updates, either.)

I don't imagine this has anything to do with it, because it works as expected locally, and it didn't change for v1.1, but here's the routing code:
https://github.com/POPWorldMedia/POPForums/blob/master/src/PopForums.Web/Areas/Forums/Extensions/RouteBuilders.cs

Comment: I suspect that `ForumRouteConstraint` fails and it matches default route(`{area}/{controller}/{action}`) on azure environment.

Comment: But it doesn't. Like I said, it works as expected locally. That code has been around for six years. It's not just that route, it's all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after redeploying twice, this resolved itself. That's even more concerning, that routing would break like that, and that it didn't.